# wxPython: Automatically resize the frame to keep free space out

Tags: python, layout, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a very simple wxPython app which consist of a `frame` containing:

1. `control1` that keeps its aspect ratio on resize.
2. `control2` that keeps its height constant and fills the entire width of the `frame`.

I'm using a `BoxSizer` with the `SHAPED` attribute set for `control1`.

---

It looks fine initially, `control1` is in dark-gray, `control2` is in black:
[image: initial layout of the frame]

However, when I resize the frame horizontally (by dragging the left or right border of the window), as the `frame`'s height is kept constant, and `control1` keeps its aspect ratio, there is empty space on the right (in red):
[image: frame resized horizontally]

I would like it to resize *vertically* at the same time as I am resizing it horizontally, so that there is no empty space, i.e.:
[image: frame resized horizontally with automatic height adjustment]

Of course, the same problem happens when resizing it vertically (by dragging the top or bottom borders of the `frame`).

---

Here is the source code:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
frame.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0xFF, 0, 0))

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

control1 = wx.Panel(frame, size=(640, 360))
control1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x40, 0x40, 0x40))
sizer.Add(control1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.SHAPED)

control2 = wx.Panel(frame, size=(32, 32))
control2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
sizer.Add(control2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

frame.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Just change to `sizer.Add(control1, 1, wx.EXPAND)` Setting the `proportion` to 1 means it can change its size in proportion to other items in the sizer. In this example, it's the only one.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't keep the aspect ratio of `control1`, which I need Thanks.

Comment: The sizer has a GetItem function, from this you can access GetRatio for `control1`. Use that ratio to determine the size of the Frame if resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the code like this:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
frame.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0xFF, 0, 0))
frame.SetMinSize((640,430))

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

control1 = wx.Panel(frame)
control1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x40, 0x40, 0x40))
sizer.Add(control1, 20, wx.EXPAND)

control2 = wx.Panel(frame, size=(640, 32))
control2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
sizer.Add(control2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

frame.SetSizer(sizer)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```